# My EC2 Instance goes from 5% to 100%. What to do?

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2

I have set up an EC2, t2.micro instance running Ubuntu and Apache.
The only thing running on the server is a Laravel website with a SQL database.

I have only set it up in the last week and I am the only person using the system.

Over the last two days, the CPU% has gone from around 5% all the way up to 100%.
The instance is unresponsive, I can't log in via EC2 instance connect, an the IP is unresponsive.

My CPU Credit Usage is 0, until this spike occurs, then it lags the usage.
NetworkIn Bytes doesn't appears to be a leading indicator.

I can fix it by rebooting the system, but that isn't practical if Im going to release it for other people to have access.

What I need help with is where do I start to look into to understand whats causing this?